# How to restart celery by celery it self

Tags: python, celery

I have celery workers running if different network. All of them using the same rabbitmq server. I want to know how to notify each worker to upgrade to the latest version?. I did't find a way to do this.

multi restart have to run outside of the worker.

auto reload didn't working.

I don't know what happens after broadcast the pool_restart command.

Do I have to shut them down and use supervisord to restart them?

Here is my request:

task add return x + y

After I start the worker, I change the task add to return x + y + 1

but the result still be x + y.

pool restart didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the --autoreload is the flag you want

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html

Comment: I finally use supervisor to restart

Comment: --autoreload didn't do anything